# I am not sure why this Javascript only covers half the screen

Tags: javascript, animation

I am making a variation of a whack-a-mole game where I have a number of bugs scurrying across the screen. Problem is, those bugs only want to scurry on half the screen, and I'm not sure why. The game is at: https://hmcka.github.io/100days/day38/day38.html .

I've gone through my CSS file line by line, and I've tried several different ways to measure the screen's width (code examples commented out below) in Javascript. Any idea what is keeping these bugs sidelined?

```
function moveItSmooth() {
const bug = randLocale(animals);
var rect = bug.getBoundingClientRect();

let posX = rect.top;
let posX2 = (Math.round(Math.random() * (screen.width - rect.width)) + 150);
//tried screen.width;
//tried window.innerWidth
//tried window.width

let posY = rect.left;
let posY2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - rect.height));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let posX = rect.top;`

You are setting the X coordinate as the top, and the Y coordinate as the left. They should be flipped since you are using the width to calculate X (left-right) and height to calculate Y (top-bottom).

You can see that the bugs often travel way beyond the bottom of the screen because their vertical range is the same as the width of the screen.

```
bug.style.top = posX + 'px';
bug.style.left = posY + 'px';
```

should be

```
bug.style.left = posX + 'px';
bug.style.top = posY + 'px';
```

Comment: Yeah. I kept thinking that it looked flipped, but I couldn't figure why. This makes sense. Ty.